# Update Oracle table from SAS dataset

Tags: sql, oracle, sas, oracle-pro-c

How do I update an Oracle table in SAS from a SAS dataset?

Here's the scenario:

1. Trough a libname I load an Oracle table into a SAS dataset.
2. Make some data processing during which I UPDATE some values, INSERT some new observations and DELETE some observations in the dataset.
3. I need to update the original Oracle table with the dataset I've modified in the previous step - so when there's a match between the keys of the oracle table and the dataset, then the values will be updated, when there's a missing key in the oracle table, then it will be inserted, and when there's a key which is in the Oracle table but already deleted from the dataset, then it will be deleted from the Oracle table.

NOTE: I can not create a new table in Oracle. I need to make the "updating" on the original table.

I was trying to do it in two step using MERGE INTO and DELETE, but there's no MERGE INTO in PROC SQL.
I would really appreciate any help.

EDIT: I was also thinking about just truncating the oracle table and inserting the rows (talking about 4-5000 rows per procedure run), but seems like there's no built in truncate statement in PROC SQL.

Comment: Though you can do it using Sql pass through in SAS, Why can't you do the update in Oracle itself? Also, please mention what you've tried till now along with the code.

Comment: It is a part of a SAS webservice which is called in SOAP request. So basically it is a part of an automated process in the background when the users call the procedure/webservice. So all in all I can't just call it all the time in Oracle manually.
I tried proc sql delete all the rows from the Oracle table and then insert into all the observations from the dataset into the "truncated" table in oracle.
The modified observations usually are 5 - 10% of all the rows, so I delete and insert ~~90% of the observations for no reason.

Comment: It is working fairly quickly, I was just thinking if there's a more efficient way.

Comment: Can't you upload the transaction data to a temporary table oracle, then use explicit pass through to update the main table?

Comment: @Quentin thanks for the suggestion, but it's a strict schema in which I can't create or drop tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using the below,

## Method 1:

```
PROC SQL;
insert into <User_Defined_Oracle_table>
select variables
from <SAS_Tables>;
QUIT;
```

Above creates a table that resides in the same database and schema.

```
  PROC SQL;
    connect to oracle (user= oraclepwd=);
    execute(
    UPDATE <Oracle_table> a SET <Column to be updated> = (SELECT <Columns to update seperated by commas>
    FROM <SAS_table> b
    WHERE a.<VARIABLE>=b.<VARIABLE>)
    WHERE exists (select * from <SAS_table> b
    WHERE a.<VARIABLE>=b.<VARIABLE> ))
    by oracle;
    QUIT; 
    
    PROC SQL;
    connect to oracle
    (user= oraclepwd=};
    execute (truncate table <SAS_table>) by
    oracle;
    QUIT;
```

This is one of the efficient ways to update the oracle table.
Please refer to [`Update Oracle using SAS`](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/106-29.pdf) for more information.

## Method 2:

```
LIBNAME Sample oracle user=  password= path=  schema= ; run;
PROC SQL;
UPDATE Sample_Oracle.<Table_Name> as a SET <Variable_Name> = (SELECT <Varibales>
FROM <Sas_table> as b
WHERE <A.Variable_Name>=<B.Variable_Name>)
WHERE exists
(select * from <Sas_table> as b
WHERE <A.Variable_Name>=<B.Variable_Name>);
QUIT;
```

This method takes longer processing time of all methods.

Also,

## Method 3:

```
%MACRO update_oracle (SAS_Table,Oracle_Table); 

Proc sql ;
select count(*) into: Count_Obs from <SAS_Table> ; Quit;

%do i = 1 %to &Count_Obs;

Proc sql; 
select <variables to update seperated by commas> into: <macros> ; Quit;

PROC SQL;
UPDATE &Oracle_Table as a
SET <Oracle_Variable_to_Update>=<Variable_macro_created_above>
WHERE <A.Variable_Name>=<B.Variable_Name> 
QUIT;

%end;
%MEND update_oracle;
%update_oracle();
```

The macro variables SAS_Table and Oracle_Table represent the SAS Dataset that contains the records to update and records to be updated in oracle, respectively.

Method 3 uses less processing time than method 2 but not as efficient as method 1.

Comment: Thanks. The truncate sulution was very helpful. The issue with the update solution is, that the table "b" is not a real oracle table, instead it is only a SAS dataset. So in this case the pass trough SQL is not a solution. Or is it?

Comment: Sorry @MartinToth that should be SAS_Table. I have now updated the code. Thanks.

Comment: Aha, I see. Will try it out in a few hours on my work PC and write the outcome. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: I don't think it will work unless you first upload the SAS dataset to Oracle.  Without doing that, Oracle won't be able to query the SAS dataset.

Comment: @Quentin that's right, I tried it out. Unfortunately in order to use this solution I would need to upload the dataset to oracle at first. So it does not work, which I can't, because I have no privileges to create tables.

Comment: @Quentin I get that ... Thanks for heads up. I have now edited the code. @ Martin Toth I have updated 2 more methods you can use even if you don't have access to create tables in Oracle. Can you give them a try and let us know any challenges.

Comment: @PraneethKumar thanks for the provided solutions. The 3rd is actually pretty clever. Never thought of using proc sql in a macro %do loop. I am now marking your answer as a solution for my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Surely there are UPDATE and INSERT methods in proc SQL.  Also, check if SAS will allow you to do other SQL operations  "execute immediate" (such as PL/SQL will allow) where you can construct the SQL statement as a string, then send it to Oracle to execute.

Comment: Hi Roger. Thanks for the suggestion. I am aware of this solution, but unfortunately you can't pass SAS objects such as a dataset to a pass trough SQL code. It is meant to be executed directly on the Oracle server instead of the SAS server, but it can use only Oracle objects in the query.